# Install specific gdal version

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dependencies

I want to install gdal 2.1.* version:

```
apt-cache show gdal-bin | grep Version
Version: 2.2.2+dfsg-1~trusty1
Version: 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
Version: 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1
```

But have problems:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin=2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdal-bin : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt install gdal-abi-2-1-0`?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, but maybe it can be done in more automatic way?

1.

```
apt-cache search gdal-abi
libgdal20 - Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
```

2.

```
apt-cache show libgdal20 | grep Version
Version: 2.2.2+dfsg-1~trusty1
Version: 2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
```

3.

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal20=2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin=2.1.0+dfsg-1~trusty2
```